# Can't enter spaces into basic usage of AvalonEdit

Tags: avalonedit

I placed a simple instance of the AvalonEditor into a WPF usercontrol and it ignores any spaces I try to enter. Other text is fine however. I have not configured any highlighting or changed the control template. Do I need to configure a setting on the control to accept spaces?
thanks

```
        <avalonEdit:TextEditor
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            Rob was here
        </avalonEdit:TextEditor>
```

Comment: I should add that I am using the AvalonEdit control inside the context of a WindowsFormsHost control, inside of Excel. When I step through the code, TextArea.OnTextInput is never called when I type spaces, but it is called for other characters. When i run a test app outside of Excel/WindowsFormsHost, it behaves normally. Something about running in that hosted environment is causing this apparently.

Comment: I mean ElementHost, not WindowsFormsHost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Here is my solution:

1. Inherit from AvalonEdit TextEditor class
2. Override the OnPreviewKeyDown callback (or subscribe to PreviewKeyDown event).

```cs
public class MyEditor : CSharpCode.AvalonEdit.TextEditor
{
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Space)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                Document.Insert(CaretOffset, " ");
            }
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        }
}
```

I set the event to handled and append the space. I think this the editor will add the space either on keyup or on a later event, which is overriden by a keybinding I did on a container I put the editor in. This behavior is different to the textbox default, which does catch the space automatically.

I know this is a little bit hacky, but at least it works for now. I think if I will do another keybinding on another key I will have to handle it in the callback as well. If someone has a better (and more general) solution please let me know.